# with urgency or urgently?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrase-request, collocations

I believe my question refers to collocations and also to which is the most common way of saying that I will send a message alerting people that they have to solve a situation urgently.

I've done some research on google to see the ocurrences, but there were no results for "forward this message with urgency" or "pass this message with urgency".

Is it ok and common to say "I'll pass this message on to our team with urgency?" Or "I'll forward this message to our team urgently"?

Answer (score 4):

The adverb "urgently" has a very similar meaning to the prepositional phrase "with urgency".  So you could use either in this context.

I'm not quite sure that "urgent" is the right meaning.  Perhaps "right now" or "right away", or "without delay" would fit the sense better.  "Urgently" means "in a way which demands immediate action", but your actions don't demand immediate action, they *are* immediate actions.

> I'll forward this message to the team right away.